PowerBi API Workspace info scan not starting
This code worked fine until this afternoon. Workspace list is retrieved but gets stuck in an endless loop of Scan Status 'NotStarted'. Not sure what I'm missing here any help appreciated.
var pbiClient = GetPowerBiClient();

//DBHelper dbh = new DBHelper();
//dbh.getSQLConnection(pbiClient);

AdminGroups workspaces = pbiClient.Groups.GetGroupsAsAdmin(2000);

IList<ModifiedWorkspace> mw = pbiClient.WorkspaceInfo.GetModifiedWorkspaces(null, true);

IList<Guid?> wrkspcs = new List<Guid?>();

foreach (ModifiedWorkspace ag in mw)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ag.Id + "--" + workspaces.Value.First(ws => ws.Id == ag.Id).Name);
    wrkspcs.Add(ag.Id);
    if (wrkspcs.Count > 99)
        break;
}

RequiredWorkspaces rw = new RequiredWorkspaces(wrkspcs);
ScanRequest pwsi = pbiClient.WorkspaceInfo.PostWorkspaceInfo(rw, true, true, true, false, true);

while (pbiClient.WorkspaceInfo.GetScanStatus((Guid)pwsi.Id).Status != "Succeeded")
{

    Console.WriteLine(pbiClient.WorkspaceInfo.GetScanStatus((Guid)pwsi.Id).Status + " |" + pwsi.Status + "| ");
    Thread.Sleep(30000);
}

WorkspaceInfoResponse wsir = pbiClient.WorkspaceInfo.GetScanResult((Guid)pwsi.Id);

foreach (AdminGroup ag in workspaces.Value)
{
    try
    {
        WorkspaceInfo tmag = wsir.Workspaces.First(ws => ws.Id.ToString() == ag.Id.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(ag.Id + "|" + tmag.Users.Count + "| -- " + ag.Name);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ag.Id + " Not in Scan Result");
    }
}

